# Векторный конвейер

Tags: архитектура

Здравствуйте, помогите разобраться. В учебнике есть такая формула T = S + q * N,
где T- время выполнения операции, S - время подготовки конвейера, q - время получения результата на конвейере, N - длина вектора. Получается, операция над частями вектора выполняется не параллельно, а последовательно. Что  входит в это время q?

Answer (score 1):

**Ответ**: Да, последовательно, но блоками

---

На [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80#.D0.98.D0.BB.D0.BB.D1.8E.D1.81.D1.82.D1.80.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B1.D0.BE.D1.82.D1.8B) очень доступно объяснено.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение? Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения так, чтобы он был самодостаточный.

Comment: То есть если в векторном регистре векторы длиной 100, а длина конвейера 10, то он будет делить вектор на блоки по 10 компонент и их последовательно складывать? Тогда k будет равно отношению времени на блок к числу компонент в блоке?

Comment: @Wanti да, вы правы.